# Which effects do not persist to a new game?

Tags: diablo

In the original Diablo, after defeating Diablo (or whenever you feel like it) you can start a new game with the same character retaining your character stats and items. Except that some things do not persist to the new game.
The ones I know about are:

- Effects from the Gloomy shrine
- Effects from the Weird shrine
- The unique Lightforge mace (according to [Jarulf's Guide](http://www.bigd-online.com/JG/JGFrame.html), this morphs into a different item when you start a New Game)

Are there others?

Note 1: Not sure if there would be differences between single-player and multi-player, but I'm playing single-player.

Note 2: Obviously, available quests, quest status, monsters, dungeon-layout, and whatnot all do not persist to a new game. I am asking specifically about items, item stats, and character stats/spells.

Comment: Actually I was pretty sure that everything remained as it is

Comment: Are you sure the Gloomy and Weird shrine effects don't carry over? Those are permanent stat mods to everything you're carrying at the time, and like other permanent mods (like oils, or the durability reduction from the warrior's repair skill) I'd expect them to carry over across resets.

Comment: @ToxicFrog I haven't verified personally, but [diablowiki](http://diablo2.diablowiki.net/D1_Shrines) states that those effects do not carry over to a new game.

Comment: @ToxicFrog I have now verified personally with results in [this answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/133462/41309). Some permanent stat mods are less permanent than others it seems.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I've read completely through a couple of guides and tried many things out for myself. Here is what I have learned:

### Character Modifications

There is really nothing that changes for your character between games. The only one that does is that you lose any spell effects that you currently have, which you would anyway for simply entering town.

- Modifications to your max mana via Sacred, Ornate, and Fascinating shrines persist to the new game
- Modifications to your max health via Black Death zombies persist
- Items you are wearing and carrying persist. Items left on the ground in town do not.
- Spells effects do not persist such as Infravision and Mana Shield.
- Any town portal you have does not persist.
- Openings to Caves, Catacombs, and Hell are based on your level in multiplayer and therefore appear in the new game. In single player, these openings are always closed on a new game.

### Item Modifications

Not all item stats persist to a new game!

- The Lightforge mace morphs when you carry it to a new game. (I haven't seen this happen and have no idea what it morphs into)
- Effects from the Weird shrine do not persist to a new game. This was doubted (for good reason), so here is some proof:

Sword affected by Weird Shrine:
[image: Damage 3-9]

Same sword after starting new game:
[image: Damage 3-8]

- Effects from the Gloomy shrine do not persist to a new game. This was also doubted, so here is more proof:

Helm affected by Gloomy Shrine:
[image: Armor 14]

Same Helm after starting new game:
[image: Armor 12]

- Effects from Hidden Shrine **do** persist. The helm pictured above was also affected by a Hidden Shrine.
- Changes based on Warrior's Repair skill and Sorcerer's Recharge skill persist.
- Current durability and spell charges persist

Note: Any effect received from a Goat Shrines or Cauldron will persist in the same manner as one from the named shrine.

Answer (score 1):

I realize that this thread is long dormant, but I found another exception worth noting. The Constricting Ring morphs when carried over to a new game as well.  I was wearing it when I defeated Diablo and when I started a new game, it had morphed into the Ring of Engagement, which...ironically, I already had in my inventory.   The really weird part though is that the max resistance was permanent.  I was maxed out across the board even when I took the ring off.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add 5 cents: you only carry items that you have in inventory. OK this was obvious and you learn this first time you beat the game. BUT: you only carry items that you had from your last save, not when you killed Diablo.

And since Diablo may drop something juicy, here's advice. You cannot move when you kill Diablo, you are stuck while he is bleeding and then final animation starts. You can pick up item if it is next to you. What I did to get the Diablo's item is to spawn tons of guardians, then cast Telekinesis spell so pointer is changed and ready to fire the spell. Then wait and hope guardians will finish Diablo. When they do and your Telekinesis is ready, just fire it and get the item. Now you have to save to get this item in new game. And now you have Diablo's item in new game and you can identify it to see what it is.

Btw, I doubt I ever kept his item as I usualy already had something better, but they did sell for lot of gold.